# Markov processes: Hitting times for a point form an i.i.d. sequence

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

Say that I have a recurrent time-homogenous diffusion process X (continuous strong markov process) and two points $x,y$. If $X_t$ goes from $y$, to $x$ and then back to $y$ again we denote it as a "bump".

Define the stopping times iteratively:

$t_1$ First time a bump finishes

$t_2$ The time it takes from the first bump finished till the 2nd bump finishes

and so on...

(So $t_1+...+t_n$ is the total time for the n'th bump to finish ). Is it true that they form an i.i.d sequence? It seems obvious to me, and proving independence is trivial since $X_{t_n}=y$ is constant , but somehow the stationarity keeps eluding me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the variables $t_i$ are independent and identically distributed.  The independence follows directly from the [Strong Markov property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property). That gives that $t_i$ is independent of $t_j$ for all $j < i$.  The Strong Markov property and time-homogeneity together imply that 
$$P[X_{s + t_i} \in A | t_i] = E[X_s \in A| X_0 = y]$$
for all $s \geq 0$.
That yields that the $t_i$ are identically distributed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you eloborate the last part regarding stationarity, where you use The Strong Markov property and time homogeneity? I guess you mean
$P[X_{s+t_i}\in A\vert t_i]=P(X_s\in A\vert X_0=y]$ ?

Comment: @Conformal  Yes, sorry, I left an expectation in there, should have been a probability.  The time homogeneity tells you that in general that $P_{X_0}[X_{s + t} \in A | X_t] = P_{X_t}[X_s \in A]$ (the subscript tells you where you are at time zero).  The Strong Markov property basically lets you substitute $t_i$ into that equation for $t$.